# How to create DatePicker with two components (Months & Years), which also would show All months as the option to select the whole year?

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I'm a beginner in iOS development, so maybe it's a dumb wish from my side.
Nevertheless, the thing is: I'm making a Statistics section of my app, which should let user choose a certain month and year and he would get some statistics results for that period of time of different entries he entered before.
The hard part is that I also would like to implement 'the whole year' selection for months component, so user could choose, for example, "All" for month and "2013" for year and he would get statistics for the whole 2013 year. I was unable to find any examples like this on this site or in google at all, because in all cases DatePicker returns you the certain date, and not the range of the dates.
So I came to conclusion, that maybe it's not the way how you do such a task in iOS? One of the options I thought about was to implement two date pickers, one for 'from' and one for 'til', but it seems a bit tedious...
Basically, I want user to be able to select certain month or a year to see the statistics for that period of time.
I'd appreciate if you could give me some advice how you usually proceed with tasks like this one in iOS.
Thanks.

update: Thanks everyone for the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a `UIPickerView`. Setup your picker and data source so it has two components. One for the months (Jan-Dec plus your "All" option) and the other for the year.

Comment: how can i set month year from UIPickerView based on json timestamp

Answer (score 3):

Use UIPickerView as rmaddy said. And customize the data source for the picker using the appropriate delegate methods like this.

Set date source (ex.)

```
soureYear = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"2001",@"2002",@"2003",@"2004",@"2005",@"2006",@"2007",@"2008",@"2009",@"2010",@"2011",@"2012",@"2013", nil];
    soureMonth = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Jan",@"Feb",@"Mar",@"Apl",@"May",@"Jun",@"July",@"Aug",@"Sep",@"Oct",@"Nov",@"Dec", nil];
```

Delegate methods.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
     if(component == 1)
         return [soureMonth count];
    else
        return [soureYear count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    if(component == 0)
        return [soureYear objectAtIndex:row];

    return [soureMonth objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

And get the selected items from the picker like this

```
-(IBAction)selectedItem
{
  NSLog(@" %@", [soureYear objectAtIndex:[sample2 selectedRowInComponent:0]]);
    NSLog(@" %@", [soureMonth objectAtIndex:[sample2 selectedRowInComponent:1]]);
}
```

You will get what your are expected exactly.

Comment: This doesn't support the "All" option. It would also be better to build the list of years dynamically at runtime. And the list of months shouldn't be hardcoded either. Get the localized month names from an `NSDateFormatter` using the `shortMonthSymbols` or `monthSymbols` methods.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways in which you can implement this.

1. Create a custom `UIPickerView` that pretty much imitates the behavior of `UIDatePicker`, but adds an "all months" row.
2. Add a `UISwitch` somewhere in your view hierarchy that enables "all months". When it is switched on, remove the month component from your date picker, and add it back when the switch is turned off. This is very similar to what Apple does in the Calendar app when you create a new event.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, there is a nice UIComponent in github that can be used for this purpose.
Link to component: [DRK MonthSelector](https://github.com/DRK1004/MonthSelector).